# javascript tree control + permalinks and back/forward buttons for navigation

Tags: javascript

Here's the task at hand. I need to implement a fully client-side tree that will work finely with permalinks and back/forward buttons for navigation.

E.g. I open a page with such tree control, expand some nodes, then press back and it collapses the last expanded node, then press forward and it expands the subject node. Finally I copy the url of the page and send it to my colleague - she clicks the url and the tree gets its nodes open to reveal the same tree structure that I see on my screen.

I'm looking for a JavaScript tree control that would fit the following list of requirements:

(Mandatory) Support for asynchronous node retrieval.

Possibility to hook into expand/collapse events to invoke custom logic that will serialize tree state into url anchor.

API for programmatic expanding/collapsing of given nodes, so that I don't have to emulate clicks when deserializing tree state upon pageload.

I've already had some experience with jsTree and jQuery treeview.

The problem with jsTree is that it uses <a> tags to render nodes, which messes up url anchors on click. After a couple of hours I've managed to migrate it to <span>'s, though my solution works only in Firefox. Not as good as I'd like.

Another thing happened when I tinkered with jQuery treeView. At first I was embarassed by its "not in active development" status, though upon a second glance it appeared to be a simple yet powerful widget. The async demo looked excellent so I tried to reproduce it at my PC and with my data. But then I faced a weird bug - when my JSON service returned lazy nodes (i.e. ones that had `hasChildren` set to `true`), the treeview immediately expanded those and rendered the "loading" gif, though without loading anything. I tried to debug this glitch, but I'm really not that smart to understand how all those callbacks and aspects interact with each other. At least not within the time window I had.